# Number of Regions for the data?

Tags: hbase

In how many regions HBase will store the below data.

row1, cf1:ABC, 100 
row1, cf1:DEF, 200 
row1, cf1:AEC, 300 
row1, cf2:AEC, 400

Basically, all the Rows has same rowkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same row (same row key) will be stored in the same region. You are using two column families so they'd be in different HFiles (note that a region large enough will reside on multiple HFiles anyway, at least until compactions)